# I am new to python and i want to calculate the string of the column in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I have attached a screen shot of my excel. I want to calculate the length of every in Salary column. [I want salary length to be printed next to the salary column of each tring.

I am using following code but not able to  print the data

```
import pandas as pd


# reading csv file
data = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/python work/nba.csv")

# dropping null value columns to avoid errors
data.dropna(inplace = True)

# converting to string dtype
data["Salary"]= data["Salary"].astype(str)

# passing values
data["Salary Length"]= data["Salary"].str.len()

# converting back to float dtype
data["Salary"]= data["Salary"].astype(float)

# display
data][1]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! Do you have any specifics about the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. but my salary_length is not getting printed in the excel sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the dataframe as a csv. You can use: `data.to_csv("C:/Users/Desktop/python work/nba_with_salary_length.csv")`

Comment: No problem, can you mark this answer as correct please :)

Comment: my above code is giving me extra 2 counts.for eg: if my data count is 10 its giving me 12. can you help me in this.

Comment: You should probably ask that as a separate question. But maybe if it’s consistent you can just subtract 2? 